How to clean saucepan after boiling oats in milk?
Everytime I make oats in milk boiled in saucepan, it leave a dired scum sort on the wall and base of saucpan which is very hard to get it off with sponge. What methods can I use to make it easy for it to clean?

Sponges get very gunky from this kind of thing. Use a rigid brush to remove most of the material, then a sponge only to clean the bare metal.

Soak the pot in a solution of dishwashing liquid and vinegar. Make sure the water is hot doesn't have to be boiling though.
Leave it overnight. Come back the next day and you should be able to get most of it off.
You may need to repeat the process.
As far as the wall goes. Just spray the same solution on the wall, leave it for 10 min and then wipe off.
Good luck

My hack isn't cleaning the pan, but preventing the porridge sticking in the first place.
If you stir it while preparing, it shouldn't burn or stick to the pan.
If you don't want to eat it all, transfer the rest of the porridge to a bowl. Then fill the pan with water immediately to prevent the residue from drying out.

Good idea, will try. with spoon does it matter spoon or steal?

I tried but still that stuff would stick to base

When I wash something like that I try to remove most of it with my gloves and hot water and after I removed most of it I use the sponge. Works with grease, peanut butter etc.

Provided the "scum" isn't burned on, fill the pan with water and place it back on the stove, heat the water up, and let it cool off before attempting wash it.

Fill the saucepan up with water. You want enough water in the pan to cover the residue left from cooking.

Turn the stove on and heat the water up until small bubbles start to form on the bottom of the pan.

Turn the stove off. Leave the water in the pan, and let the pan cool down to room temperature.
This gives the residue a good soak.

Pour the water out.

Fill the sink with hot water, adding a normal amount of dish soap.

Wash the pan like normal, and rinse with clean water.


Soaking the residue in hot water for a while should allow the residue to soak in the moisture, which allows it to loosen from the walls of the saucepan. Water, heat, and patience does wonders for cleaning — especially after cooking oats or oatmeal.
